Google tag not firing in container loaded and container quality
I just had google tag installed on the website, setup the google tag in GTM and tested it - but for some reason it does not fire/active on "container loaded" - why is this? I can see in google analytics, in debugview, that it receives something, because it does react when I click around on the site.
I should also mention that GTM tells me that the container is low quality, because "Some of your pages are not tagged" - We have installed a new container on the site, because the another one was very old and from what i could understand from what everybody online was saying, it would be best to start from scratch. So the site is new, however the domain is not. I´m noticing that the URL´s are all the old URL´s from the old site and none of them are tagged, like all 500+ pages - however it also says i should wait 24 hour..
I have not published the only tag i have made yet, which is just the Google tag - the one that is not firing.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
